# Trying to find this brand

Tags: plumbing

We have an original kitchen faucet in our 1940s home. The connection is very difficult to find, but this symbol is on the gooseneck (seems like the gooseneck is not original) so I want to see if this company makes them still.

[image][image]

Comment: I know you ask about being able to find replacement parts for something that is almost 70 years old but I suggest that the grief and aggravation of trying to find it is just not worth it over purchasing a new unit. There are a plethora if styles to choose from.

Answer (score -1):

That's an old American Standard logo.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We usually encourage longer answers with supporting information.

Comment: Title of the post is "Trying to find this brand." Can you explain how a "longer" answer would have helped here?

Comment: Sorry; trying to help you understand why your post was downvoted (and no, it wasn't me).